# how to track a finite data stream from start to finish?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-nifi

We are building a web crawling mechanism and would like the end-user to see the collected results as fast as possible as well as being notified when all data is inside the Database. 
The collection results pass minimal ETL processing. We are looking for an ETL that will notify when the entire finite stream is processed (as well as some progress if possible). The stream is split to a set of Zip files + a file containing the list of zip files (which will arrive asynchronously to the ETL when the stream is fully crawled).

We looked at apache flink and apache nifi. Apache flink supports batch processing and the client can wait till batch is done, but here the data is more like a finite stream which means processing should start before all the data is available and end based on another file listing all the zip files. Apache nifi seems more suitable for this job using notify and wait. will it work with nifi? is nifi designed for such cases? can nify notify on progress and finish of the finite stream? what are the drawbacks if any? any other option?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Flink stream that is bounded. I'd create a custom `SourceFunction` that uses the "zip file list" to decide when to terminate.